# xcode cocoa osx app: Does enabling break points for all exceptions effect the app store build/.ipa build?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, breakpoints

I've uploaded my mac build to the app store. I enabled break points for all exceptions. Will this by any chance effect the app on the app store? I don't think it will, but want to make sure. Don't want to reject my app and reupload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breakpoints only work when running in the debugger so, no, they will not have any effect on an app sent to the AppStore.

However if your app hits an exception when running on a device it will crash unless the exception gets caught, which is unlikely. Using the exception breakpoint during development is useful as it stops execution when the exception happens so you can get more info about what happened. Without the breakpoint the exception will almost always lead to a crash.

Keep an eye on crash reports in iTunes Connect to see if people are running into the same crash on a regular basis. If they are you have work to do.